# "TypeError: _camelize.default is not a function" in React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, snowpack, react-bootstrap-nav

Using pre-built components from:

1. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/
2. https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/

I'm trying to build a navigation bar, but getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: _camelize.default is not a function

http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-bootstrap.Navbar.v1.5.2.js [:41:55] 

pascalCase@http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-bootstrap.Navbar.v1.5.2.js:41:55
createWithBsPrefix@http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-bootstrap.Navbar.v1.5.2.js:48:51
Navbar_1<@http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-bootstrap.Navbar.v1.5.2.js:603:50
createCommonjsModule@http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-bootstrap.v1.5.2/common/createChainedFunction-36b17a02.js:14:5
@http://localhost:8080/_snowpack/pkg/react-bootstrap.Navbar.v1.5.2.js:570:36
```

This is not the first use of react-bootstrap components on this project - others have worked fine. The problem started specifically on usage of these components (Navbar and Nav).

As far as I'm aware I've got all the necessary JS in my `index.jsx` (from: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/):

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';
```

and the necessary scripts in my `index.html` (from: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#browser-globals):

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-bootstrap@next/dist/react-bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin </script>
<script>var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;</script>
```

**The code**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import '../src/App.css';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state={}
  }

  render () {
    return (
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand href='#home'>Text</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">        
          <Nav.Link href='#home'>Home</Nav.Link>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
    )
  };
}
```

So I'm lost as to where this error is occurring? Am I missing a js file somewhere?

Comment: You don't need jQuery and bootstrap.js. Just bootstrap CDN and react-bootstrap package should do. But before writing the answer what are you using jQuery and bootstrap.js for?

Comment: Why are you importing via `import` and `script` both? In simple terms just ensure the packages are installed using `npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap` and then use it in your App.js. The Browser Globals are not needed and also importing JQuery is not needed.